# How to decerase execution time while executing stored procedure in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure like this:

```
alter procedure [dbo].[fetch]
@locid integer 

as 
begin
SET NOCOUNT on
  select * from transaction_tbl where locid=@locid
end
```

While executing this i am getting around 1500 records..that is taking around 35 seconds, is there any way to decrees this time

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, the way to speed up the query is to add an index on `transaction_tbl(loc_id)`. I want to suggest that such a simple stored procedure should really be implemented as an inline table valued function:

```
create function udf_fetch (@LocId)
    @LocId int
)
returns table
return(select *
       from transaction_tbl 
       where LocId = @Locid;
      );
```

You can then call it as:

```
select *
from dbo.udf_fetch(@LocId)
```

So you can use the results in combination with other tables in a `from` clause.

Answer (score 0):

There probably isn't a one answer works here, but usually when this is the case, you need to add an index to your your table.

Make sure you have an index on the `locid` field.

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX (indexname)
ON transaction_tbl (locid)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx

Comment: how to add index to table